# Proving that $f:\mathbb{R}_0^+ \to \mathbb{R},~f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 4$ is injective using direct proof from definition

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-verification

> Given function $f:\mathbb{R}_0^+ \to \mathbb{R},~f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 4$ prove that it is injective.

Using definition of injectivity $(\forall x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}_0^+)(x_1 \neq x_2 \implies f(x_1) \neq f(x_2))$ I'm doing the following:

$$x_1^2 + 4x_1 + 4 = x_2^2 + 4x_2 + 4$$
$$x_1^2 - x_2^2 = -4(x_1 - x_2)$$
$$x_1 + x_2 = -4$$
$$x_1 = -4 - x_2.$$
Since domain is $\mathbb{R}_0^+$ it is apparent that $x_1 \neq -4 - x_2$ and hence function is not injective.

---

Is my final argument correct? In cases like that, shall I use definition instead of counterpositive?

Comment: No,  there is the other solution $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: Why would you do this? Just differentiate it.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I would like to. But we can't, our TA on compulsory calculus tutorials requires us to do this by hand from definition without differentiation.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam could you write this as answer in expanded form please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is fine, but you can end a step earlier: $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$ implies $x_1+x_2>0$, so $x_1+x_2=-4$ is a contradiction.

However you have better making evident where you're using the hypothesis $x_1\ne x_2$.

---

Proofs of injectivity are often times simpler with the contrapositive: “if $f(x_1)=f(x_2$ then $x_1=x_2$”.

Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$; then, as in your steps,
$$
(x_1^2-x_2^2)+4(x_1-x_2)=0
$$
so
$$
(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2+4)=0
$$
Since $x_1+x_2+4>x_1>0$, we conclude $x_1-x_2=0$.

Comment: In case of contrapositive, $x_1 + x_2 + 4 > x_1 \geq x_2 > 0$, right?

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity No, you don't need to assume $x_1\ge x_2$. Just the facts that $x_2>0$ and $4>0$ imply that $x_1+x_2+4>x_1>0$. You can even note that the statement is true also over the interval $(-2,\infty)$, because in this case $x_1+x_2+4>(-2)+(-2)+4>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your final argument is not correct.
Instead you have (from your calculation):
Since $x_2 \geq 0$ that would imply $x_1 <0$ which is impossible (because out of the domain): therefore f is injective on the domain.
It would also be better to give your assumptions: suppose there exists $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $f( x_1)=f(x_2)$...

Answer (score 1):

$\exists (x_1,x_2) \in [0,+\infty)^2 : x_1^2+4x_1+4=x_2^2+4x_2+4 \; \implies$

$(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2+4)=0 \implies$

$x_1=x_2 $ since $x_1+x_2+4\geq4$.

thus $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$f(x)=(x+2)^2$$ so if the function has domain $\Bbb R$ then the points
$x=t-2$ and $x=-t-2$ have same image for all $t$ so the function $f$ could not be injective. However with domain $\mathbb{R}_0^+ $ it is in fact injective and strictly increasing on its domain because is of the quadratic form $x^2$.